# How to refresh a dropdown list in JQuery without using selectmenu('refresh')?

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I want to refresh a dropdown(select) after getting response from the server. How can I do this?
I am using jquery.js (version 2.1.3). And this is my HTML code,

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    <Select id="dd" class="form-control">
        <option value="0"> List </option>
        {{#each listValue}}
            <option value="{{value}}"> {{text}}</option>
        {{/each}}
    </Select>
</div>
```

In the above code, the value of `listValue` will be obtained from the server. So, the list needs to be refreshed, if the value is changed in the server.
I am getting the updated list from the server. But, I do not know how to update the dropdown menu. The value in the server will be updated, when a record is added. I want to refresh the dropdown when a record is added.

To add a record, I have a button next to my dropdown. When this button is clicked, a modal will be shown to enter the value. Once the 'Add' button in the modal is clicked, the entered value will be added in the server. After successful addition of record, I am sending a HTTP request to get the updated values.

And this is the code to get the updated values in my js file,

```
MyModule.responseList = function(res){
    var listValue = res.content;
    //What should I do here to refresh the dropdown with this listValue
}
```

The listValue will be like this,

[image]

The listValue contains the updated values. Now, I just want to update the dropdown with this value. 
I have searched in google to refresh the dropdown in jQuery. Almost all the solutions suggested to use selectmenu('refresh').

But I want to refresh the list without using `selectmenu('refresh')`, as I am not using jquery-ui.js.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You need to provide a working example, at least the name of the plugin you are using, or this should be closed by offtopic reasons

Comment: Just remove old HTML and generate new HTML

Comment: If I remove old HTML and generate new HTML, then all the values entered in the form are lost.

Comment: Are you using any template engine? or any mvc framework like Ember Angular?

Comment: `I am getting the updated list from the server`. How? AJAX? Can you show us your AJAX? This is really an unclear question.

Comment: Or you share a working example, or this will be voted to close in few minutes

Comment: I am using `HandleBars` and `AJAX`

Comment: I am not facing any problem with AJAX. I am getting the correct values from the server. I just want to update my dropdown with the new values. @MarcosPérezGude

Comment: If you show how you receive in AJAX the data, we can show you how to construct the new options. Otherwise, I insist, this should be closed as offtopic. Read carefully this and then edit the question with a working example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask || http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have updated my code with the response from the server. Do you need any thing else from my side? @MarcosPérezGude

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108635/discussion-between-deepika-masilamani-and-marcos-perez-gude).

Comment: Please, advice me in Monday, today I'm not in a computer. I can help you now with your new example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According with the details you've attached, you can refresh the `<select>` like this:

```
MyModule.responseList = function(res){
    var listValue = res.content;
    var $select = $('select#dd');
    $select.empty(); //remove all current options

    // iterate through new options
    for(var i = 0; i < listValue.length; i++) {
        // create a new option
        var option = $('<option/>').attr('value', listValue[i].value).text(listValue[i].text);
        $select.append(option); // append new options
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I will try this code and let you know the result..

Comment: May I know what is `select#dd`? Is it the ID of my <select> menu?

Comment: Yes, it targets your `<select>` tag by the `id="dd"`. First I empty all options and then append all new options, by this mode it works.

Comment: Ok ok.. I got it now.. This works.. Thanks a lot.. But after adding a record, it defaultly selects the first value. Why is it so?

Comment: That's because it doesn't have a first option and there's no `<option>` with selected attribute. If you need to have the first option in blank, you can add after `empty()`method the next: `$select.empty().append('<option selected></option>');`

Comment: If I use this `append` method, then the same record will be added twice in the select menu. So is there any way to select the added record?

Comment: No, if you don't mark the added option with some new parameter. If you return the global object with a `selected: true` parameter and for all other choices `selected: false` it's easy to make with a single `if()`

Comment: okay.. Do you have any example for this? I am a newbie to jQuery and I am not much familiar with it. So, Sorry for the silly questions.

Comment: The server part is managed by you, I tell you that you  need to modify the returned object to add a parameter

Comment: Ok ok.. But is there any way to do it in jQuery, without changing the server code?

Comment: No, you can't know what's the change with your current code.

Comment: Ok.. will try to change my current code to select the added record. Thanks a lot for your help..

Comment: Youre welcome. Came back if you have another specific question :)